# How can I create a custom Property for my assembly?

Tags: .net, assemblies, attributes

How can I create a custom property for my .Net assembly which would then be visible under the Details tab in Windows explorer?

Something to sit parallel with "File Description", "Type", "Product Version"... etc

Update: To quote my comment to Lars ... "Whilst I would have liked to do this from within Visual studio, that is certainly not my priority. Actually I hope to integrate any solution into an existing nant build process. So affecting the assemblies post compile is entirely acceptable. Have you ever heard of such a tool?"

Further Update: I'm not sure if what I'm talking about is an attribute or not, to clarify a little what I would like to creat in an entry in the following property page...

[image]

Comment: Don't you mean custom attribute instead of property?

Comment: Updated question with screen-shot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your compiler does not support it. AssemblyFileVersionAttribute and all work because the compiler generates a win32 resource in your assembly called [VERSIONINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058.aspx) with that information in it. That is what windows is reading. Other attributes are just saved as metadata along with your code.

You could make a tool to change the VERSIONINFO resource after you compile.

Comment: Whilst I would have liked to do this from within Visual studio. that is certainly not my priority. Actually I hope to integrate any solution into a nant build process. so affecting the assemblies post compile is entirely acceptable. Have you ever heard of such a tool?

Comment: Any resource editor could do that. Like http://www.heaventools.com/rtconsole-update-version-info.htm

Answer (score 2):

Its not the answer yet, but one 1/2 way hack is to use:

```
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("One Line of Content Here")]
```

And that shows up under "Comments".

*(still researching, this is something I've wanted for a while.)*

Comment: I get the distinct impression this isn't possible through visual studio. my google-fu is not weak, and the internet does not seem to currently hold the answer.

Comment: Not true for win10. There is no __Comments__.

Answer (score 0):

The only tool that can control any field of VERSIONINFO structure from the command line and hence is able to add an additional property during a build process is Resource Tuner Console:
http://www.reseditor.com/rtc-solution-version-info.htm

The $199 price seems a bit high... but if you don't want to spend days mucking around with C/C++ then it's a steal.