# Anyone know of a free/Cheap command-line resource editor for managed win32 exes/dlls

Tags: command-line, editor, resources

I have been recommended ["Resource Tuner console"](http://www.heaventools.com/command-line_resource_editor.htm) but it's a little out of my price range.

I'm looking for something that could be launched from a nant build script and told to stamp an exe with an additional property as described in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191812/how-can-i-create-a-custom-property-for-my-assembly).

Comment: Programmer related != programming related try superuser.com

Answer (score 3):

Build a NANT task or a small program using [ResourceLib](http://resourcelib.codeplex.com/).

Comment: This was just what I needed. Now I can do the resource modifications I want in code rather than using a Process :-)

Answer (score 2):

Resource hacker can be found here, btw: http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

Answer (score 2):

I think I just found my (and possibly your) ultimate solution for this one:

verpatch /va foodll.dll %VERSION% %FILEDESCR% %COMPINFO% %PRODINFO% %BUILDINFO%

Available at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/VerPatch.aspx?msg=3207401

Free with **full sources** (Code Project Open License (CPOL) license)

Answer (score -1):

Hi my name is Archit and few monts age i felt for same question...
Now,
There are many tools which will give you command line editing ,
Resource hacker : Free and good one,
it provides scripting and saving resources go through help file where u get hell lot of examples about that ,
by the way u only asked for cheap OR free utilities ,
but there are several tolls which can perform efficiently (not free one)
if u want some more util call me ...
and yes most of the paying resource editor tools provide command line editing free.....means u can download trail and go for cmd line editor absolutely free....