# Editing resources of a PE file using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, embedded-resource

Is there any way to edit the resources of a PE (Portable Executable) file using Visual Basic, if so, how do I go about it?

If there isn't a way, could somebody point me in the direction of a Resource Editor that works from command line?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to programatically edit PE files in VB.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a command line resource editor on [Google-Code called Rescle](http://code.google.com/p/rescle/), written in C++.
Because it is open source, you have two options:

1. Use AS IS, issue commands and parse output in your program.
2. Build a DLL from that, and use it directly in your code.

Also [see this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200403/anyone-know-of-a-free-cheap-command-line-resource-editor-for-managed-win32-exes), or an extract from there:

- [ResourceLib](http://resourcelib.codeplex.com/) (C#)
- [XNResourceEditor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) (Delphi)

As an alternative, there exists a [paid tool](http://www.heaventools.com/command-line_resource_editor.htm), for $200+.