# How to add custom details to the dll/exe "Details" tab in the properties sheet?

Tags: .net, msbuild, properties

When one opens the "Details" tab found on the properties sheet of a dll/exe there are many items there, like

- File description
- Type
- File version
- etc...

Most of them (if not all) are governed by the AssemblyXXX family of attributes, like `AssemblyTitle` and `AssemblyDescription`.

My question is how can I inject additional custom details? I do not want hacks, like utilizing description to hold this information. I would like my custom details to be first class citizens of this "Details" tab - each on a dedicated line with the respective title.

Alternatively, I can settle for having an additional TAB in the dialog for my custom details.

Thanks.

**EDIT1**

MSBuild based solutions are also welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191812/how-can-i-create-a-custom-property-for-my-assembly

Comment: Yep. It is a duplicate. Missed that one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a custom Property for my assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191812/how-can-i-create-a-custom-property-for-my-assembly)