# VERSIONINFO - ignored custom values

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows-shell

I'm currently developing a .NET project which uses [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to build an executable during runtime.

I would like to show some custom values in Properties/Details tab of the built exe so I did a lot of research on the topic. I found out that these values are read by Windows Explorer shell from resources embedded in the executable. Next steps were to create a .RC file according to [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), adding my custom values in the StringFileInfo section, compiling it to .RES using Resource Compiler from MS and then embedding it into exe using [/win32res compiler option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f2f5x2e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (it is just like opening Project Properties and choosing .RES file on the Application tab in Visual Studio).

I thought that this will be a pretty working solution - but unfortunatelly it isn't. My Windows 7 Explorer shell isn't showing custom values... What I did wrong? Is it possible to achieve this that way at all?

EDIT: My .RC file content is [here](http://pastebin.com/SQDb6qeE).

Comment: Hard to say what you did wrong since you didn't show any details. You'll want to show the resource file at the very least. I'm also a little sceptical that explorer will show your custom values in the details pane of the properties dialog. What evidence do you have for that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've added link to the content of my res file. I must admit that I don't have any evidence for that, nor against. I have only some clues I've found on the Internet, I've seen many threads like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191812/how-can-i-create-a-custom-property-for-my-assembly) but none of them answers this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows will not display your custom values in the details pane of the properties dialog. The values that are displayed are hard-coded in the shell and the shell simply will not parse your resource and look for values that it knows nothing about. So, what you are attempting to do is doomed to failure I am afraid.

As an aside, you do need to null-terminate strings in your resource script. So instead of:

```
VALUE "FileDescription", "Test file"
VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.0"
// etc.
```

you need:

```
VALUE "FileDescription", "Test file\0"
VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.0\0"
// etc.
```

Comment: I was afraid that this cannot be done. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: The shell does display custom values

Comment: @Andrei Not here it doesn't.