# Extend Application properties?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I know how to extend the AssemblyInfo.cs by custom Attributes:

```
[Assembly: AssemblySourceUrl("http://www.microsoft.com/thisismycoolprogram")]
```

(where AssamblySourceUrl is a custom Attribute inherited from System.Attribute)

And I can read that information in C#. But that assembly property is not shown in explorer when I right click onto my application and select "Properties".

Is there a way to display this property in the files property inside Windows Explorer?

Comment: Compiler generates CLI metadata from your custom attribute, but explorer can't interpret CLI metadata or display it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a custom Property for my assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191812/how-can-i-create-a-custom-property-for-my-assembly)